# Setting parameters from another class

Tags: java

What I am trying to do is to have different calculation methods for complex number. I have already created all the calculations for the rational number, and it is required to create complex number by using the rational number class that I used before. Here is how I created the rational part (incomplete version)

```
public class Rational {
int numerator;
int denominator;
// Task 3: add the missing fields

public Rational(int numerator, int denominator){
    this.numerator = numerator;
    this.denominator = denominator;
    // Task 4: complete the constructor
}


public Rational add(Rational other){
    Rational result = new Rational(0,0);
    result.denominator = denominator * other.denominator;
    result.numerator = (numerator * other.denominator) + (denominator * other.numerator);
    return result;

}

......
......
......


public Rational divide(Rational other){
    Rational result = new Rational(0,0);
    result.denominator = denominator * other.numerator;
    result.numerator = numerator * other.denominator;
    return result;
    // Task 4: complete the method

}
```

Now my task is to create exactly the same thing as this one, but just in complex number version. Here's what I've created:

```
public class Complex {
Rational real;
Rational imag;
// Task 6: add the missing fields


public Complex(Rational real, Rational imag){
    this.real = real;
    this.imag = imag;
    // Task 7: complete the constructor
}

public Complex add(Complex other){
    Complex result = new Complex(); ///Here is the problem!!!
    result.real = real.add(other.real);
    result.imag = imag.add(other.imag);
    return result;
    // Task 7: complete the method

}
```

when I want to create new complex number to operate the complex addition, I don't know what should I as as the parameters since it has to be based on the rational class. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to have a constructor without any parameters. `public Complex()`

Answer (score 1):

Why not

```
public Complex add(Complex other){
    Complex result = new Complex(other.real, other.imag);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I still wondering how to utilize this in the main method. When I create like a example in main method (let's say, 3 for real part, and 2i for imagine part, how do I make a new complex number if it requires to insert rational number format?

Comment: Looking at your code, it seems that you have to create `Rational` values first, from which you can create `Complex` Objects.

Comment: That's the part where I'm struggling. If I need to create Rational value in the complex number class, should I create it in the class, or in the constructor?

Comment: Sorry, no idea, why don't you try it and see?